# error of using k (Display Stack Backtrace) command in "immediate window" of C# VS 2013 on win 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I need to debug an exception of "access violation" in C# (web forms applications) of Visual Studio 2013 in win 7.

There is no "call stack" button in "debug" --> "windows".

So, I tried to use k (Display Stack Backtrace) commands in "immediate window" by following

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I typed

```
    ~6010 kd    // 6010 is thread number
```

in immediate window.

but, I got error:

```
End of expression expected
```

in immediate window.

Any help would be appreciated.